# Use of Repository in WPF MVVM Application for Network Application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I currently made an Information System that is capable of viewing information from the database in SQL Server Management Studio. I am now planning on creating the add, edit delete. This application will be installed in many computers with 1 server machine. Do I have to use a repository or not in implementing this? This repository is connected with the add and delete event args.

Comment: You can also use CQRS if that suits more for your situation. Repository is common for CRUD operations, CQRS you'll in systems that require scale or to catch the users intent. CQRS usually some side by side with event sourcing. So you must know which of the two you want go with, both have their up- and downsides

Answer (score 0):

**NO**

From your description, you are building simple CRUD application and there is no need for repository.

Repository responsibility is take care of storing domain object (from [domain driven design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design)) and obviously, you don't have any domain objects yet.

You can use Entity Framework that already implements simple repository for you.